# Databricks streaming with aws S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, databricks

Below are some queries related to Databricks streaming with aws S3 bucket.

1. Is it possible to get round trip execution time while streaming read and write file(.csv) from S3 bucket? If possible than please explain in details.
2. How to use existing python notebook in streaming using call the function with passing parameter?
3. How to get file(.csv) path while streaming read the file (.csv) using readStream?

Comment: Where are the queries?

Comment: 1. Is it possible to get round trip execution time while streaming read and write file(.csv) from S3 bucket? If possible than please explain in details.

2. How to use existing python notebook in streaming using call the function with passing parameter?

3. How to get file(.csv) path while streaming read the file (.csv) using readStream?

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the batch duration in the streaming metrics.
2. Put the functions in a separate notebook and call %run on that notebook before the stream starts, then you can use them.
3. Use the function input_file_name to retrieve the file name.